# "He would have nothing of it"

Tags: grammar

> Even in the Nazi fervor, he would **have nothing of** the ideology. He cherished his ideal of peace.

What is this idiom, which I cannot find in my dictionary?

It is not an idiom but I don't know what it means.

Comment: Context is useful here. But without any context it means "Even if he is pro-Nazi, he wouldn't posses/(or might be 'support') any of his ideology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's similar to the idiom *["have none of"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+none+of)* which means:

> <sub>[From Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/have-none-of-sth)</sub>
>
> to refuse to accept, agree with, or support something

Rephrased:

> Even in the Nazi fervor, he **refused to accept** the ideology. He cherished his ideal of peace.